# parameter estimating in lattice signature scheme

Tags: signature, lwe, ring-lwe

when reading [BDLOP18], I run the lwe-estimator with the recommended parameters in Table 2[image] , but the result of hermite factor is 1.007, this result is bigger than the recommended hermite factor 1.0035[image]

Comment: Could you please include a full reference (and preferably a link) in your question for BDLOP18? Is it "More Efficient Commitments from Structured Lattice Assumptions", or is it a different paper?

Comment: yes, More Efficient Commitments from Structured Lattice Assumptions, [BDLOP18](https://eprint.iacr.org/2016/997.pdf).